# Copy files into Folders based on Year

Tags: linux, bash

I need to be able to copy photos from a source folder into year folders based on the modification date of the file.

I am looking for a bash script on linux to do this

Comment: Most file systems do not store creation/birth date.

Comment: I am looking for modified time it doesn't need to be created time

Answer (score 2):

rsync wil not help you. You need bash and some linux commands:

Bash script:

```
file=myimage.jpeg
modtime=$(stat --printf=%Y $file)
year=$(date -d @$modtime +%Y)
mkdir -p "$year"
cp "$file" "$year"
```

Remarks

- Rsync is good to copy files but not for the sorting task
- The above example uses file modification time because file creation time is not available on some file systems
- If you want to do the above for multiple files, use a bash `for` loop

Comment: My `stat` on GNU linux works as expected but on BSD that syntax errors out with `stat: illegal option -- -`  but GNU date(1) and BSD date(1) works as expected with `date -r $file '+%s'`

Comment: Any ways `date -d @` still does not work on BDS` date(1)`...

Comment: My opinion you can use `date -r $file '+%Y'` directly so you don't rely on `stat(1)`.